# Google assistant delete phrase

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am working with Google Assistant with Dialogflow interaction and have one issue.

I created intent Delete and want to delete something from my conversation. I added 'delete', 'delete it' phrases to the Training phrases. Enabled webhool call for this intent.

In my conversation I say 'delete' or 'delete it' but my conversation is end with <'earcon'>. Without any request or response info.

[image]

[image]

The question is, why does Google Assistant end the conversation after 'delete' phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It is related to the **actions_intent_OPTION** event which intercepts Delete intent. If you use List or Carousel for rich responses where actions_intent_OPTION event is applied, try to disable it.
More details can be found on reddit post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/huinnu/dialogflow_actions_intent_option_intercept_delete/